# How can I fix WPGraphQL not passing image URLs after deploying my Headless Wordpress website?

Tags: wordpress, next.js, headless, wp-graphql

I'm trying to deploy Headless Wordpress website with NextJS.
Everyting was working fine on local but after I deployed Wordpress by Hostinger VPS, Graphql is not getting image url...

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AwvFc.png)

I'm using mysql Ver 8.0.33-0ubuntu0.22.04.2 and PHP 8.2.6 just if it's related.

I have no clue what is the cause of this and have been struggling for days.
Is anyone have the same issue and fixed?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Have you found the solution? I just moved my site to a different server and the image path doesn't change.